# Laravel 4.1 querying hasMany relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

My question is regarding querying relationships in Laravel 4.1 / ORM.

I have a "Labs" model and a "Dates" model. The two are configured to have a 2 way relationship:

**Dates.php:**

```
  public function lab(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Labs');
  }
```

**Labs.php:**

```
  public function dates() {
    return $this->hasMany('Dates');
  }
```

In my controller, I want to query my Labs, and get the Lab which has a date of $today:

```
$today = new DateTime('today');
$activeLab = Labs::hasDate($today);
return $activeLab;
```

Something like that... But this of course doesn't work.

How can I retrieve a "Lab" where a Date it owns matches a date I provide?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: additional code progress..

```
$today = new DateTime('today');
$today = $today->format('Y-m-d');
$activeLab = Labs::whereHas('dates', function($q) use ($today){
        $q->where('dates.date', $today);
    })->get();

return $activeLab;
```

**Final edit - Solution:**

Thanks to deczo we were able to determine the problem. By default Eloquent uses the model name for linking to the foreign key. My model was named Labs (plural), so it looked for `labs_id` in `dates` table. You can specify the foreign key in the `Labs` model `hasMany()` statement:

```
public function dates() {
  return $this->hasMany('Dates', 'lab_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$search; // value to find

Lab::whereHas('dates', function ($q) use ($search) {
   $q->where('dates.someColumn', $search);
})->get();
```

It will return `Labs` having related date(s) matching given `WHERE` clause.

Change the relation on `Labs`:

```
public function dates() {
  return $this->hasMany('Dates', 'lab_id');
}
```

Comment: this throws a QueryException for me:

`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dates.labs_id' in where clause (SQL: select * from labs where (select count(*) from dates where dates.labs_id = labs.id and dates.date = 2014-06-20) >= 1)`

Comment: Probably you should have `lab_id` there. Anyway show the code you have.

Comment: deczo, I have edited the original post with the code. Also the `lab_id` does exist in the `Dates` table, that was a typo, my apologies.

Comment: I have noticed it is looking for `dates.labs_id`, where the spelling should be `dates.lab_id` -- not sure why it is adding the plural s?

Comment: For `hasMany` Eloquent takes model name to guess the foreign key, and since your model is plural, it looks for `labs_id`.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know you could manually assign the foreign key in the hasMany call --- thank you!!!!